# access ang pass value in url (nav back)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I started navigating from main page to transaction page and then from transaction page I navigate to details page now from details page I have a go back feature and then I pass then I pass data with the state so that when I navigate back I can access it from transaction page.

Now the issue is when I am from main page and I first go to transaction page this would cause an error which is `core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'extras')` because I only pass state when I navigate back from details page.

How do I only access `console.log(this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example);` from transaction page when I only navigate from details page. If I am from main page and navigate to transaction page it should not show error core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: . Thanks for any idea.

#code for accessing data on transaction page

```
console.log(this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example);
```

#code

```
private  _generateLocationFormForApproval() {
    this._dealService.generateLocationSubmission(this.dealId)
    .subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        if (res.isSuccess) {
          this.absoluteUri = res.absoluteUri;
         }
      },
      error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
      complete: noop,
    });
  }
  
  
  goBack() {
    this._route.navigateByUrl(`${this.headerOptions.breadCrumbs.backLink.link}?tab=2` , { state: { example:  this.absoluteUri } });
  }
```

Comment: [Spelling, grammar, and punctuation are important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Your post has been evaluated as potential spam. I'm a foreigner and would appreciate a warning in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling `getCurrentNavigation` in the constructor?

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   console.log(this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example);
}
```

If not, try it.

Comment: yes I called it on the constructor

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gLu09PD . the getCurrentNavigation is in transaction component. If I navigate from main page to transaction component this would cause an error because I did not pass state from main page to transaction component , I only pass and want to pass state from details component to transaction component